# Clonezilla multiple disks restore to single disk

Tags: clonezilla

I have a clonezilla image from a machine that had 3 seperate disks (one partition per disk).

I want to know if I can restore that image to another computer that has a hard drive that's much larger than the original, but only has one drive.

Clonezilla is stating that it can't do this automatically, and perhaps I should try `cnvt-ocs-dev` but I've no idea what that means (Google is less than forthcoming with information about it too).

---

Ok so I found out what `cnvt-ocs-dev` is, and that allows me to move source/destination targets between physical disks, but it doesn't seem to be able to move the partition as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the down sides to using clonezilla and similar image backup methods.  You will need to create three partitions on the new disk that are at least as large as the 3 old disks, and restore each partition individually.